# EnableMenuItem only works for the Close button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi, user-interface

I wanted to write an *Helper* Class to disable any menu item like the minimize and maximize buttons, but the API function `EnableMenuItem` only works for me only for the **CloseButton** and the "Close" option of the system menu.

Here is a little test that I've realized

```
Public Sub Disable()

    Me.CloseItem_State = &H2 ' Disabled

    For x As Integer = 0 To 999999999 ' Loop over all posible constant values...
        EnableMenuItem(Me.MenuHandle, x, &H0 Or Me.CloseItem_State)
    Next
    ' At this point, ONLY the Close button and close option were disabled.

End Sub
```

The minimize and maximize constants by MSDN are these:

```
Maximixe = &HF030
Minimize = &HF020
```

But like I've said I can't disable them neither I can't turn them to Grayed state.

And is not only about the TitleBar, the same thing happens for the popup system menu, only the close button and the close option wew disabled when I use `EnableMenuItem` function like in the code aboive...

I'm missing something?

Comment: Why are you avoiding just setting the MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox to false?

Comment: @LarsTech that was just an example because are not more buttons on the titlebar, like I've said I would like to be able to disable any of the options, for example the "restore" option and "size" option. from the system menu.

Comment: Is not a solution for me to remove the items, I've learned how to remove items, I have problems trying to disable them.

Comment: Your loop looks a little inefficient.

Comment: It may be that the system is reenabling them again. Normally you would do this in response to the `WM_INITMENU` message.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter thankyou so much! intercepting that message solved my problem, thankyou again. if you want to give a short answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system probably resets the states of those items dynamically. The normal mechanism for enabling/disabling standard menu items is to process the `WM_INITMENU` message, which is sent immediately before the menu is displayed.

Comment: Also it isn't necessary to loop over all ids. Use the menu positions. The easiest way to hit all menu items is to start with iPos=0 and loop with MF_BYPOSITION until EnableMenuItem returns -1. Than stop the loop.

Comment: Maybe you could know which message I need to intercept for the same issue but about this other constant?:         ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the window menu as a result of a mouse click.
        ''' </summary>
        SC_MOUSEMENU = &HF090.   I try to disable that command but I still able to click right button to open the system menu.

Comment: That's because it's not a menu command itself. It's processed by the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message so if you handle that message and don't pass it through to `DefWindowProc` (only if `wParam == SC_MOUSEMENU`) it should block it.

Comment: While that is possible, it is a lot less troublesome to simply adjust the appropriate [Form Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Windows.Forms.Form_properties.aspx). No more intercepting all potential ways of opening the system menu. And inevitably missing some of them.